# Read pixel colors of an image

Tags: image, excel, vba, colors, pixel

In VBA, how can I read the color value of each pixel of in an image?

I found [this solution](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=67567&lngWId=1) in VB 6.0 but it doesn't apply directly in VBA.

Comment: if the code uses API then it's rather possible to implement it into VBA setting some references to API's functions...

Comment: What file type are you asking about?  Any in particular? Maybe a list of file types? Different file formats will be storing color information differently so reading different types will require knowing what we will be required to read.

Comment: The answer below works great but if you actually want to scan each pixel (rather than click on it ) then this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998565/scan-image-pixel-by-pixel-in-vba/46004570#46004570   does the job nicely and all in VBA (no graphic libraries etc)

Answer (score 11):

Try the solution posted on this site here : 
http://sim0n.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/vba-q-how-to-get-pixel-colour/

I had to change a ByRef to a ByVal but apart from that it works well. Insert a picture using Insert > Picture and assign a macro to the on click event . I've just made it set the colour of cell A1 to the colour you click on, but I'm sure you get the idea.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As POINT) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal x As Long,     ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As POINT) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#End If
Private Type POINT
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Sub Picture1_Click()
    Dim pLocation As POINT
    Dim lColour As Long

    Dim lDC As Variant
    lDC = GetWindowDC(0)
    Call GetCursorPos(pLocation)
    lColour = GetPixel(lDC, pLocation.x, pLocation.y)
    Range("a1").Interior.Color = lColour
End Sub
```

To use it, place a picture in a worksheet, right click on the image and assign this macro to it.

Comment: Same here, with additional info: you can also use images that you simply paste in the sheet (the "Insert > Picture" procedure is not mandatory). Thanks again +1 and thank you @KM Hs